# how can I hide a part of javascript from IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is my javascript function to open a jquery dialog.

```
   ('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,
          show: 'slide',        
          width: 800,       
          height: 700,        
         close: function() {           
    }   
});             
$('#dialog_click').click("callback",function() {            
   $('#dialog').dialog('open');                 
   return false;
});
```

How can I hide the part `show: 'slide,` from IE ?

Comment: `window.navigator.userAgent`

Comment: Your question seems like a second-generation question. For example, the real problem is that you are having trouble with `slide` in IE, which is why you are asking to remove it in IE. You might be able to solve the original problem if you ask.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Is this because of a particular problem in older versions of IE? What versions are you testing? Have you tried it in IE9 and IE10? They're actually pretty good browsers (especially IE10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var options = {
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,       
          width: 800,       
          height: 700,        
         close: function() {           
    }   
};
if ( ! $.browser.msie){
  options ['show'] = 'slide';
}

$('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog(options);
```

Comment: I'm glad that i could help.

Comment: beware: the `$.browser` feature in jQuery is deprecated, and has been removed entirely from the more recent versions. It is not recommended. (in fact, browser detection in general is not recommended for most use cases)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if ( ! $.browser.msie){
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "show", "slide" )
}
```

Comment: beware: the `$.browser` feature in jQuery is deprecated, and has been removed entirely from the more recent versions. It is not recommended. (in fact, browser detection in general is not recommended for most use cases)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,       
          width: 800,       
          height: 700,        
         close: function() {           
    } 
});

if(!$.browser.msie) {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "show", "slide" );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but in my case it is not working. The dialog is not opening when I added this. Is any other problem with the code

Comment: beware: the `$.browser` feature in jQuery is deprecated, and has been removed entirely from the more recent versions. It is not recommended. (in fact, browser detection in general is not recommended for most use cases)

Answer (score 2):

jquery has removed support for jQuery.browser.msie from version >= 1.9

so

```
var opts = {
    autoOpen : false,
    modal : true,
    resizable : false,
    show : 'slide',
    width : 800,
    height : 700,
    close : function() {
    }
};
if (!/msie/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
    opts.show = 'slide';
}

('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog(opts);
$('#dialog_click').click("callback", function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several workarounds for this (*conditional comments* for the whole script, altering the property later, etc) but noone has posted a solution that does EXACTLY what you asked: **excluding a portion of javascript only in `IE`**.

Then take a look at this:

```
   ('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,

        /*@cc_on @*/
        /*@if (true)

        @else @*/
          show: 'slide',        
        /*@end @*/

          width: 800,       
          height: 700,        
         close: function() {           
    }   
});             
$('#dialog_click').click("callback",function() {            
   $('#dialog').dialog('open');                 
   return false;
});
```

`IE` won't include `show: 'slide',`, while `non-IE` browsers won't read the **`Conditional Compilation Statements`** , so the condition will fall in the (not-commented) else part.

Read more on [Conditional Compilation Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kx09ct1%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is several thing you can do.

First there are conditional comments , ie

```
<!--[if !IE ]>
    <script>
       $('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         resizable: false,
         show: 'slide',        
         width: 800,       
         height: 700,        
         close: function() {           
         }   
       });             
       $('#dialog_click').click("callback",function() {            
         $('#dialog').dialog('open');                 
         return false; 
       }); 
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Or you can check jquery browser variable , as other guys are pointing.

Also if you are going this way, and you really want to target old version of IE you can use some functions specific to it ( like attachEvent )